# Pandas dataframe to structured array with Boolean series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe which I wish to convert to either a NumPy records array or structured array. I am using Python 3.6 / Pandas 0.19.2 / NumPy 1.11.3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[True, 1, 2],[False, 10, 20]], columns=['a','b','c'])

print(df.dtypes)

a     bool
b    int64
c    int64
dtype: object
```

My attempts are below:

```
# record array
res1 = df.to_records(index=False)

# structured array
s = df.dtypes
res2 = np.array([tuple(x) for x in df.values], dtype=list(zip(s.index, s)))
```

However, the Boolean type doesn't seem to be evident in the `dtype` attribute of these results:

```
print(res1.dtype)

(numpy.record, [('a', '?'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])

print(res2.dtype)

[('a', '?'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')]
```

Why is this? More generically, is this the only exception, or should we have to check manually each time to ensure the dtype conversion has been processed as anticipated?

**Edit**: On the other hand, it seems the conversion *is* correct:

```
print(res1.a.dtype)     # bool
print(res2['a'].dtype)  # bool
```

So is this just a display issue?

Comment: '?' is bool type in numpy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html. i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously, NumPy chooses `?` to represent Boolean. From [Data type objects (dtype)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types):

```
'?' boolean
'b' (signed) byte
'B' unsigned byte
'i' (signed) integer
'u' unsigned integer
'f' floating-point
'c' complex-floating point
'm' timedelta
'M' datetime
'O' (Python) objects
'S', 'a'    zero-terminated bytes (not recommended)
'U' Unicode string
'V' raw data (void)
```

Confusingly, the NumPy [Array Interface](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#__array_interface__) for access from C extensions uses a different mapping:

```
t   Bit field (following integer gives the number of bits in the bit field).
b   Boolean (integer type where all values are only True or False)
i   Integer
u   Unsigned integer
f   Floating point
c   Complex floating point
m   Timedelta
M   Datetime
O   Object (i.e. the memory contains a pointer to PyObject)
S   String (fixed-length sequence of char)
U   Unicode (fixed-length sequence of Py_UNICODE)
V   Other (void * – each item is a fixed-size chunk of memory)
```

Credit to @bobrobbob for finding this in the docs.